# Input buffer size 0 for bloom filter is not power of 2

Tags: sql, azure, azure-databricks

I'm running a huge insert query on Azure databricks SQL Warehouse :

```sql
INSERT INTO
  my_base.my_table PARTITION (project_id, simulation_id, scenario_id) 
    SELECT
```

The query is over 1000 lines but I can add it if you think it's necessary (just let my know in the comments).

I'm running this query over a databricks SQL Warehouse (type:classic, size:large).
My query is failing with the error :

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Input buffer size 0 for bloom filter is not power of 2

I do not understand the error message. Can anyone explain what could be the issue and how I can fix it ? Or maybe where should I look for a solution ?

---

Apparently, the issue could come from a version change. Initialy, my script was running over a SQL warehouse 2023.10. The error occues on upgrading to version 2023.15.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory allocation for the Databricks SQL Warehouse and then running the query?

Comment: @Naveen you mean changing the size of the SQL Warehouse ? My current warehouse is a large. I tried with both Small and XL. Same result. Let me know if you meant anything else.